# SQL datetime comparison with current datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a project which involves comparing a `datetime` field with the current date and time, and if the difference between them is 10 minutes, then I have to select some date. It involves complexity, like if the current date and time is a date greater than the field `datetime`. Does anyone has a simple solution to this?

Comment: How about example data and expected output

Comment: suppose the current datetime is 8:04:10 5/12/2016 and the field date is 7:50:10 5/12/2016, the time difference is more than 10 minutes. This is when i want to select some other field.

Comment: "some other field", which one?, do you mean the row?, another column?. Is it really hard to post some sample data and desired result?

Comment: i thought that wouldnt matter. Anyways, this time field is updated with the service run time. if the time is > 10 mins, then i have to select the serverID field. i want all the serverID which all didnt run in the last 10 mins

Comment: Still going with the word problem when you could easily post your desired result from a sample data

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very simply using [`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
IF ( SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.StartDate, GETDATE())
     FROM   TableA a) > 10
BEGIN
    SELECT  *
    FROM    TableB
END
```

This simply says that if the current time (`GETDATE()`) is more than 10 minutes past the `StartDate` on `TableA`, do something else.

Note that if `a.StartDate` is *greater than* `GETDATE()` (for whatever reason), the value of `DATEDIFF` will be *negative* - in which case, you simply change the comparison to `> -10`.

EDIT from comments:

> I want all the serverID which all didnt run in the last 10 mins

This can be trivially accomplished with the following:

```
SELECT  ServerID
FROM    TableA
WHERE   DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LastRunTime, GETDATE()) > 10
```

Here are a few "checks" you can do to see the behavior of `DATEDIFF` - the comment regarding *only* caring about minutes is incorrect, but jumping to larger intervals `DAY`, `MONTH`, etc. does cause some interesting behavior.

For example:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '05/30/2016 08:10:00', '06/01/2016 08:05:00')
```

Returns 1 (month), despite being only 2 days apart. Similarly,

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '05/30/2016 08:10:00', '06/01/2016 08:05:00')
```

Returns 2, despite the time not *quite* making it to the 2-day mark. Finally,

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, '12/31/2016 08:10:00', '01/01/2017 08:05:00')
```

Returns 1 as well.

Hopefully this helps in your understanding of using `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: I do know about DATEDIFF. here you are just comparing the minutes. Suppose the current time is 8:10 5/12/2016 and field date is 8:05 5/11/2016. It will only compare the time and not the date as the above 2 times are a day apart. Hope you are getting.

Comment: @user1801774 that's completely wrong, of course it takes the date into account and calculate how many minutes apart those dates are

Comment: I really thought it will only compare the corresponding datetime fields (i.e. only minutes, only hours etc) without considering other components of datetime

Comment: @user1801774 Try this to see what `DATEDIFF` does: `SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '05/11/2016 08:10:00', '05/12/2016 08:05:00')` -- returns 1435